# UIView animatewithduration - iOS

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation, uiviewanimationtransition

I'm trying to move a label from point A to point B using UIView animateWithDuration as below

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:3 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone animations:^(void){
        label.alpha = 1;
        label.center = CGPointMake(label.center.x , label.center.y +740);

        }completion:^(BOOL Finished){ 
         label.alpha = 0;
        label.center = CGPointMake(label.center.x , label.center.y - 740);]
```

Once the label is about to reach 740, it decelrates. Is it possible to have uniform motion to point B instead of slowing down?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:3 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^(void){ 
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change the animation option to `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear` to have the animation use remove all the acceleration and deceleration or `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn` to keep the slow start without decelerating at the end.

What you are seeing is expected and [even documented](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration:animations:) (see below). By default the animation both begins and ends slowly:

> **Discussion**
>
> This method performs the specified animations immediately using the `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut`.

Answer (score 1):

Include `UIViewAnimationCurveLinear` in the options instead of `UIViewAnimationTransitionNone`. `UIViewAnimationTransitionNone` is not meant for this kind of animation. It's meant for view controller transitions.